# Dataframe: separate ids in a cell in several rows

Tags: r, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe

```
+----+-----+-----+---------+
| A  | B   | C   | id      |
+----+-----+-----+---------+
| A  | B   | C   | 1;2;3;4 |
+----+-----+-----+---------+
```

I need to split ids separated by semicolon in separate rows as follows

```
+----+-----+-----+---------+
| A  | B   | C   |id       |
+----+-----+-----+---------+
| A  | B   | C   | 1       |
| A  | B   | C   | 2       |
| A  | B   | C   | 3       |
| A  | B   | C   | 4       |
+----+-----+-----+---------+
```

What is the simpliest way to do that?